# Internet Explorer 11 printing cuts text on the right

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-11, pdf.js

I implemented PDF.js library and I need to print a PDF from IE 11 (with a click on a button in PDF.js viewer). The problem is, IE adds page information (header, footer, page number), and cuts off text like 5cm to the right. I spent hours trying out different CSS variants for @page rule, but still can't fix it. Here are the pictures.

This is how the printed file should look like:

[image]

And this is how it looks like printed to pdf with margin-left and margin-right set to 0mm:

[image]

You see, position and size are correct, but the text is simply cut off. Now when I added 50mm to the right margin:

[image]

Now the page number is aligned with the document, and the document text is still cut off, but a little less.

I experimented with different values and I get weird results, but I can't get it to show the complete text. Tried all kinds of margins, padding, size, width, overflow: visible... Nothing works. The only way I managed to remove header, footer and page numbers is by manually setting it up in IE print settings. But then again text is cut off. And it shouldn't be the client's job to mess around with print settings, it should automatically work just fine. I found similar problems on SO but no final answer. Is this actually an IE bug which is impossible to solve? Thanks

Comment: I suggest making a CSS style sheet specifically to target IE 11 print pages. This way you can remove all page elements and reset the content to display the way you want

Comment: The app is meant to work with IE 11 only anyways, but that is my question. HOW to make that CSS stylesheet? It always cuts text to the right, even if in print preview it looks good

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can find more information about this (and other IE) printing issues here:

(IE: Incorrect printing in Internet Explorer)
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3983

There appears to be a lot of issues around printing in IE 10 and IE 11 using this pdf.js library. I am currently trying to get it to work myself. 
(My own problem is that I am getting page 2 content appearing on page 1 and having page 1 content cut off)

this (around line 3469, viewer.js)

```
canvas.style.width = (PRINT_OUTPUT_SCALE * viewport.width) + 'px';
canvas.style.height = (PRINT_OUTPUT_SCALE * viewport.height) + 'px';
var cssScale = 'scale(1, 1)';
```

seems to fix the scaling issue for me, and the comment by **himawan-r** (page setup dialog) around the 25 Apr 2015 told me how to get rid of the headers/footers.

My only real workaround at the moment is to force printing in a PDF plugin, and if the plugin is not installed, default to a standard html page with the relevant CSS queries for stripping non-printable areas.

I hope that this issue is something that is going to get addressed quickly, because I really like the pdf.js library.